# SQL Server : drop fulltext catalogs in a different database

Tags: sql-server, full-text-catalog

Wondering if anyone know how to drop a fulltext catalog from a different database? I am trying to write a stored procedure, and I need to check if a fulltext catalog exists before creating it.

I've tried

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DBName.sys.fulltext_catalogs WHERE Name = 'MyCataLog')
    DROP FULLTEXT CATALOG MyCataLog
```

(it will only drop the catalog on the same DB)

it does not work. Anyone have done it before? I googled it and still can't find a solution.

Thanks much.

Comment: What is a problem having catalog with same name in different DBs?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
IF EXISTS (select * from DATABASE.sys.fulltext_catalogs WHERE Name = 'CATALOGNAME')
```

`EXEC ('USE <DATABASE NAME>;DROP FULLTEXT CATALOG MyCataLog')`